# Bootstrap 4 content and navigation side bar Overlap issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an  application for my university. For this I used `Bootstrap-4`. I'm making 4 divisions
**header**,**content-top-fat **,**content-bot-fat **,**main-content** and **footer** I try to `fixed header`, `content-top-fat`,`content-bot-fat` and `footer`. I need to scroll only `main-content` part, after I added sidebar navigation menu its not a looking good its always `overlap` you can understand my code and image, please help me to fix this issue how to fixed this part and scroll only `main-content` part, my `main-content` part cant scroll ,

thanks

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

```css
body.mainbody {
  overflow: hidden;

  font: 13px/1.7em 'sans-serif';
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg-inverse {
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;

  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

}

.main-content{
  height: 85%;
  margin-top:5%;
z-index: -1; overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content-top {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;z-index: -1;
background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-top-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-bot-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;  z-index: -1;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background:white;
  position: fixed;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.4em 0.5rem !important;
}
#contents {
  /*position: fixed;*/

  overflow-x: hidden;
margin-top: 6.5rem;
padding: 2%;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="mainbody">
<div class="header">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="p-2"></div>
  <div class="p-2"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<!--/header-->
<div id="content-top-fat">
  <div class="add-text-fat">
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">+</div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">Add New Rate Plan</div>

  </div>


</div>
<div id="content-bot-fat">


  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><p class="rateplan-date">Thursday, April, 20, 2017
  </p></div>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="contents">
 

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.




Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with p
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Image
[image]

Comment: Are you using [Bootstrap 4 Beta](https://getbootstrap.com) or [Bootstrap 4 Alpha](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com)?

Comment: Sir im used `v4-alpha` https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: move `z-index: 5` from `.sidenav` to `.header` - does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your `.sidenav{position:fixed; top:0;}` to `.sidenav{position:absolute; top:5%;}`

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

```css
body.mainbody {
  overflow: hidden;

  font: 13px/1.7em 'sans-serif';
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg-inverse {
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;

  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

}

.main-content{
  height: 85%;
  margin-top:11%;
z-index: 0; overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content-top {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;z-index: -1;
background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-top-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-bot-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;  z-index: -1;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background:white;
  position: fixed;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.4em 0.5rem !important;
}
#contents {
  /*position: fixed;*/

  overflow-x: hidden;
margin-top: 5.0rem;
padding: 2%;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 5%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="mainbody">
<div class="header">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="p-2"></div>
  <div class="p-2"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
</div>


</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<!--/header-->
<div id="content-top-fat">
  <div class="add-text-fat">
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">+</div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">Add New Rate Plan</div>

  </div>


</div>
<div id="content-bot-fat">


  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><p class="rateplan-date">Thursday, April, 20, 2017
  </p></div>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="contents">
 

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.




Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with p
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: just change your .sidenav  div as I used above answer or which browser have you using

Comment: I updated my answer check it now. Just change .main-content margin-top:11% or 12%

Comment: sir ithink  its shoud be a   `z-index: 0;`  #content-bot-fat {
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 8%;
    padding: 1.5%;
    background: #e2dcdc;
    position: fixed;
}

Answer (score 6):

I have found the problem in your code and I have fixed it.
I hope it will help you :)

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

```css
body.mainbody {
  overflow: hidden;

  font: 13px/1.7em 'sans-serif';
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg-inverse {
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;

  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

}

.main-content{
  height: 85%;
  margin-top:11%;
z-index: 0; overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content-top {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;z-index: -1;
background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-top-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-bot-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;  z-index: -1;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background:white;
  position: fixed;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.4em 0.5rem !important;
}
#contents {
  /*position: fixed;*/

  overflow-x: hidden;
margin-top: 5.0rem;
padding: 2%;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 5%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="mainbody">
<div class="header">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="p-2"></div>
  <div class="p-2"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
</div>


</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<!--/header-->
<div id="content-top-fat">
  <div class="add-text-fat">
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">+</div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">Add New Rate Plan</div>

  </div>


</div>
<div id="content-bot-fat">


  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><p class="rateplan-date">Thursday, April, 20, 2017
  </p></div>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="contents">
 

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.




Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with p
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's just a `z-index` issue that can be resolved by moving `z-index: 5` from `.sidenav` to `.header`

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

```css
body.mainbody {
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 13px/1.7em 'sans-serif';
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg-inverse {
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 5;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

}

.main-content{
  height: 85%;
  margin-top:5%;
z-index: -1; overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content-top {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;z-index: -1;
background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-top-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}
#content-bot-fat {
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;  z-index: -1;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background:white;
  position: fixed;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.4em 0.5rem !important;
}
#contents {
  /*position: fixed;*/

  overflow-x: hidden;
margin-top: 6.5rem;
padding: 2%;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="mainbody">
<div class="header">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="p-2"></div>
  <div class="p-2"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<!--/header-->
<div id="content-top-fat">
  <div class="add-text-fat">
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">+</div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ">Add New Rate Plan</div>

  </div>


</div>
<div id="content-bot-fat">


  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><p class="rateplan-date">Thursday, April, 20, 2017
  </p></div>
</div>
<!--content-->
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="contents">
 

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.




Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with p
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.Preprocessor
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.
Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

ComponentsBootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes Sass, a popular CSS preprocessor. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.

Responsive across devices
One framework, every device.
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.

Components
Components
Full of features
With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```